# Number of positive/negative/zero eigenvalues of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

Let $B$ be an $n\times n$ matrix of rank $r$, and let $A$ be the $2n\times 2n$ matrix given by $$ A=\begin{bmatrix}I & B \\ B^t & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
How can we find the number of positive, negative, zero eigenvalues of $A$?

I have no idea for doing this, so I tried a computation with explicitly given $B$, and I am conjecturing that the answer will be as follows:

1. The number of the zero eigenvalues of $A$ equals that of $B$.
2. The number of positive eigenvalues of $A$ equals the number of negative eigenvalues of $B$ plus $n$.
3. The number of negative eigenvalues of $A$ equals the number of positive eigenvalues of $B$.

But I can't see how to prove this in the general situation. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sylvester's Law of Inertia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
I & 0\\
 -B^T&I \\
\end{array}
\right)  
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 I&B \\
 B^T&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)  
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 I&-B \\
 0&I \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 I&0 \\
 0& - B^T B \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

If $B$ is real, the rank of $B^T B$  is the rank of $B$  while the nonzero eigenvalues are positive. And then you negate it.